# Python loop for

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a loop problem - I have to read files ('f' and 'f2') and I am trying to get each line from 'f' with accession number ('acc') and find lines containing this 'acc' in file 'f2'. The loop with 'f2' is not working properly. After finding 'acc' in 'f2' it should move to next line in 'f' and start searching for 'acc' from first line2 in 'f2' but it doesn't, it seems like it starts from where it ends, are there any simple solutions to that?

```
f = open("test1.txt", "r")
f2 = open("test2.txt", "r")

for line in f:
    acc = line[0:9]
    for line2 in f2:
        if acc in line2:            
            print line2
            break
```

Comment: Is it your intention to break the inner loop just after finding the first occurence of acc in f2?

Comment: You would need to reset the file object's position, e.g.: using [`file.seek`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek). Or just read the entire file into a list first and then use that in the iteration.

Comment: This code can not be tested and does not provide enough information to debug. Please at least add the code that assigns `f` and `f2`. Also, some sample inputs would be nice. Just enough to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show how you are defining `f` or, more importantly, `f2`, but if `f2` is an open file, then you need to either open it just before your loop to read from it (so it starts at the beginning) or at least reset the file pointer (using `seek`) to go back to the beginning.

Comment: thanks, opening a file before second loop seems to work, I've tested it on small instances, now I will try on bigger one

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might work.

```
f1 = 'filename1.txt'
f2 = 'filename2.txt'
with open(f1, 'r') as first_f, open(f2, 'r') as second_f:
     list_of_accs = (line[:9] for line in first_f.readlines())
     f2_lines = f2.readlines()
     for acc in list_of_accs:
         for idx, line in enumerate(f2_lines, 1):
             if acc in line:
                print('Occurence found at line {idx} with no {acc}'.format(idx=idx, acc=acc))
```